# Is there a python TTS library that can set the fundamental frequency of the output?

Tags: library, python, audio, speech-synthesis, signal-processing

Is there a python TTS library that can set the fundamental frequency of the output? Or should I manually recognize the frequency and do FFT and adjust the fundamental frequency?

(I am trying making a vocaloid.)